# CMake - how to build Boost after downloading it with FetchContent?

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, compilation, repository

My goal is to download the Boost repository if it isn't found and then build it  the default way, i.e. using `boostrap` and `b2` tools.

I know, I can download it like this:

```
include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
    Boost
    PREFIX external_dependencies/boost
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/boostorg/boost.git
    GIT_SUBMODULES libs/system libs/serialization libs/random 
                   libs/function libs/config libs/headers libs/assert libs/core libs/integer 
                   libs/type_traits libs/mpl libs/throw_exception libs/preprocessor libs/utility 
                   libs/static_assert libs/smart_ptr libs/predef libs/move libs/io libs/iterator 
                   libs/detail libs/spirit libs/optional libs/type_index libs/container_hash
                   libs/array libs/bind
                   tools/build tools/boost_install
)   

FetchContent_GetProperties(Boost)
FetchContent_Populate(Boost)
```

**But how can I build it now correctly?** I'd like to run following commands:

```
./bootstrap.sh
./b2 headers
./b2 -q cxxflags="-fPIC" --layout=system variant=${BUILD_TYPE} link=${LINK_TYPE} address-model=64 --with-system --with-serialization --with-random
```

I'm thinking about [add_custom_target()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html) and [add_custom_command()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/command/add_custom_command.html) functions, but I'm not sure, if it's the recommended way to do this.

Comment: You are missing a call to add_subdirectory(). See the CMake documentation: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.21/module/FetchContent.html?highlight=fetchcontent#populating-the-content

Answer (score 2):

[`add_custom_target`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html) is probably better because it is declaring a target that is convenient to depend on,
using [`add_dependencies`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_dependencies.html).

You may need one target per command, and that becomes quickly annoying. So instead I would try (I did not) writing a script performing the build, let's call it `build-boost.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# This is meant to be run from the source directory of Boost.
./bootstrap.sh
./b2 headers
./b2 -q cxxflags="-fPIC" --layout=system variant=$2 link=$3 address-model=64 --with-system --with-serialization --with-random
./b2 install --prefix=$4
```

In your CMake code, you would be calling it this way:

```
add_custom_target(
  build-boost
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build-boost.sh ${BUILD_TYPE} ${LINK_TYPE} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/external_dependencies/boost-installation
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/external_dependencies/boost
)
```

After that, you are not done yet.
You should still export all the variables [`FindBoost`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html?highlight=find%20boost) usually exports, and create all expected directories in advance (under `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/external_dependencies/boost-installation`), since at configuration time the binaries and headers are not present yet.

If you complete this work, please let the community know, since this can be helpful.